# Ajax inside submitHandler form submit not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-validate

I am working on registration user,

I validate fields with jquery validation plugins.

in 'submitHandler' I called Ajax and then If response is ok then  form is submited ....but the form is not submited.but i got alert of "OK".

Here is my code,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
// Setup form validation on the #register-form element
jQuery("#reg_form").validate({
// Specify the validation rules
errorElement: "span",
rules: {
    fname:  {
    required: true,
    maxlength: 12,
    minlength: 4,
    remote: {url: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/ajax-checkusername.php", type : "post"}
    },
    lname: "required",
    phone: {required:true,number: true},
    address: "required",
    email: {
    email: true,
    required: true,
    remote: {url: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/ajax-checkemail.php", type : "post"}
    },
    password: "required",
    cpassword: {
    required: true,
    equalTo: "#password"
    },
    profile_picture: {
    accept: "image/*"
    }
},
// Specify the validation error messages
messages: {
    fname:  {
    email: "This field is required.",
    minlength: "Please enter atleast 4 characters",
    maxlength: "Too much characters",
    remote: "username already in use!",
    },
    lname: "This field is required.",
    phone: {
    required: "This field is required",
    number: "Please Enter Number"
    },
    address: "This field is required.",
    email: {
    required: "Please Enter Email!",
    email: "This is not a valid email!",
    remote: "Email already in use!",
    },
    password: "This field is required.",
    cpassword :{
    required:"This field is required.",
    equalTo:"Password Not matched."
    },
    profile_picture: {
    accept:"Please Insert Image"
    }
},
submitHandler: function(form) { 
    var frm = $(form);alert(frm);

    if (jQuery("#g-recaptcha-response").val()) {

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/ajax_verify_captcha.php", // The file we're making the request to
            dataType: 'html',
            async: true,
            data: {
                captchaResponse: jQuery("#g-recaptcha-response").val()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data); 

                //jQuery('#reg_form').get(0).submit();
                if(data=="OK"){
                    frm.submit();

                }

                //alert("everything looks ok");
              // jQuery('#reg_form')[0].submit(); 

            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("You're a bot");
                alert(XMLHttpRequest);
                return false;
            }

        });


    } else {
        alert("Please fill the captcha!");
        return false;
    }


}
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would check is the value within the if statement. Moreover you could just use (data) to see if it is defined at all or `.length` to see if it was set to anything.

```
console.log(data=="OK");
if(data.length){
  frm.submit();
}
```

You should probably return a boolean or a number and use parseInt() to ensure you compare two variables of the same data type.

Comment: thx..Hosch for your effort but after remove condition if condition it is not still working.......